# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I have the following code:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ 
  target: '.sidebar > .nav > .active', 
  offset: 120 
});

/* animate scrolling to the sidebar sublink targets to ensure proper offsets */
$('.sidebar > .nav > .active > .nav > li > a').on('click', function () {
  var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 200);
});
```

And I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
>   at HTMLAnchorElement. (site.js?v=6-PQc6gnbrcv8oGPmVGKbiMSOAf5yrI5zG6Eeo7i360:81)
>   at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3)
>   at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3)

Comment: The issue is because the jQuery object in `target` does not contain any elements. We can't tell you exactly why that is without seeing the value in the `href` of the clicked `a` element, or the rest of your HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah I did check there, I went to the examples and saw the offset.left example - looked above and it predefined offset as offset() haha will remove comment

Comment: Also quick question - what's the benefit of doing `$($(this).attr('href'))` over `$(this).attr('href')`?

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` returns a string. `$($(this).attr('href'))` returns a jQuery object, using `href` as the selector

Comment: Ah I see ok, thanks @RoryMcCrossan !

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are not selecting what you intend. Maybe the `a` is not the target. Maybe you don't have the section you are trying to select by the selector equal to href. Maybe the href is not what you think. Maybe the offset is undefined becaue jQuery can not compute it.

```
$('body').scrollspy({ 
  target: '.sidebar > .nav > .active', 
  offset: 120 
);

 $('.sidebar > .nav > .active > .nav > li > a').on('click', function () {
     var href = $(this).attr('href') || $('a', this).attr('href'),
         target = $(href);

     console.log('Href:', href);
     console.log('Target:', target);
     console.log('Offset:', target.offset());

     target.length && target.offset() && $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 200);
 });
```

Because they say:

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements > or accounting for margins set on the  document element.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with visibility:hidden > set, display:none is excluded from the rendering tree and thus has a position > > that is undefined.

Comment: The outcome of the script above is :

Href: #colors 
Target: n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#colors"}

Offset: undefined

Href: #colors

Target: n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#colors"}


Offset: undefined

Comment: Try to exoand the Object after the Target: see if the length is 0 or 1. And dtrip the garbage when you copy paste here ffs :(

Comment: Do you have some html element with the `id="colors"`?

Comment: I have one link with the id="colors"

Comment: @dewilde86 is it visible at the time you are checking its offset?

Comment: Yes its visible

Comment: Publish a sample do we can debug it.

Comment: Found the solution. Tnx for the help

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: I some other javascript code i forgot the '#' and thats why it didnt scroll to the #name